In bash, how to store stdin and stdout file handle in variable?
I have the following bash script:
STDIN='&0'
if some-condition; then
  STDIN=some-filename
fi

run-command <${STDIN}

But that errors with &0: No such file or directory.
Similarly for STDOUT.
I've tried using eval but haven't gotten that to work, either.
What needs to be done to get this to work?

Can STDIN be replaced for the whole program or does it need to be only replaced for run-command?

&0 is not a file handle. 0 is the file handle, which could be used as an "argument" for either of the distinct redirection operators < or <&.

STDIN='/dev/stdin'  # Default to stdin
if some-condition; then
  STDIN='some-filename'
fi

# Similarly, for STDOUT
STDOUT='/dev/stdout'  # Default to stdout
if some-other-condition; then
  STDOUT='some-other-filename'
fi

run-command <"$STDIN" >"$STDOUT"


That's storing file names, not file handles.  Also, it's environment specific.  Not all environments where Bash can be found provide /dev/stdin or /dev/stdout.

@JohnBollinger, Bash treats /dev/stdin and /dev/stdout (and /dev/stderr) specially in redirections.  For  redirections, they work even on systems that do not have /dev/stdin and /dev/stdout device files.

Fair enough, @pjs, but they are still file names not file handles.  This makes a difference, as the two are not used the same way.

A "file-handle" is just a number of the file descriptor. In the case of stdin it is 0. In the case of filename, you can open the filename to receive a handle to it.
stdin=0
if some-condition; then
  exec {stdin}<some-filename
fi
run-command <&"${stdin}"

Using eval is evil. Do not use it.
Prefer lower case variables for script-local variables.
You can read about exec {var}>file in bash documentation second paragraph of https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections .
Check your scripts with shellcheck.
You can read about file descriptors even on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor .
You could also, if you do not care about origin stdin, just replace it depending on condition, which would simplify to just:
if some-condition; then
   exec 0<some-filename
fi
run-command
exec 0<&-  # close it if you want

